# Facebook authentication (display=touch or display=wap) using Qt

Tags: facebook, qt

I'm currently developing an app for nokia smart phone mobile using "display=touch", however the fb oauth dialog doesn't render properly on QWebview nor QML Webview.

When I use "display=wap", the fb oauth dialog renders properly.

Is it appropriate to use WAP for Nokia smart phones?

Comment: [link](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=#############&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token&display=touch&scope=publish_stream) used for the authentication process

Answer (score 0):

I also used display=wap, the same than you since touch didn't work OK, and I didn't notice any bad side-effects on Symbian. This was some time ago though (couple of months).